# If condition in local shell after sFTP connection

Tags: sftp

I've been using the following script successfully in a local shell to move a file from one directory to another if the file size is 0:

```
if [[ ! -s /directory1/subdirectory1/file1.txt ]]
then
    mv /directory1/subdirectory1/file1.txt /directory2/subdirectory2;
fi;
```

Now I want to use the same script adding **!** to have the same command running in the local shell once the sFTP connection to our customer server has been made:

```
!if [[ ! -s /directory1/subdirectory1/file1.txt ]]
then
    mv /directory1/subdirectory1/file1.txt /directory2/subdirectory2/; fi;
```

The script is running unsuccessfully with the following error: **/QOpenSys/usr/bin/bsh: syntax error at line 1: `fi' unexpected**. I've been successfully running scripts including local shell commands after the connection thru sFTP has been made however I've been trying this one hard and not succeed. We are running iSeries V7.2. I appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to accomplish?

For bash script the ! inverts the output return.
If your would like to see an example on CLI run:

```
ls ; echo $?
```

should return 0

```
! ls ; echo $?
```

would return 1. 
Look close at the bottom of the return if your folder is full. You will a 0 or 1 depending on which way you run it.

In your example the ! is next to the if (no space) Like !if,  not ! if,  and it will invert the if into fi and then bash says that fi is not a command. 
Give it a try with a space between the ! and if and see what happens. Not sure what you need to happen.
Like I said explain your desired results and it will help someone get your answer.

Comment: I tried to comment the above post but 3 point too low.

Answer (score 0):

1. Shell escapes typically require the shell command to be entered
   all on one line. 
   Try typing

   ```
   !if [[ ! -s /directory1/subdirectory1/file1.txt ]]; then mv /directory1/subdirectory1/file1.txt /directory2/subdirectory2; fi
   ```

   (You don’t need a semicolon at the end.)
2. If you’re going to want to issue that same command many times,
   you can simplify your life by putting it into a (local) shell script. 
   Then you can run it by typing

   ```
   !my_conditional_mv
   ```

   (or whatever you choose to call it).

Comment: Thanks for your help, still does not make it happen though: `end of file' unexpected

Comment: You need to learn how to debug.  You’re doing something complicated; you need to figure out where the problem is.  If you do `!date`, what happens?  If that doesn’t work, then there’s a problem with shell escapes.  What if you write a script called `my_date` that says `#!/bin/sh` / `date` and run it with `!./my_date`?  Did you create a `my_conditional_mv` script?  What happens if you run that directly from your shell?  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your timing and concern on this. I finally got it right. I was missing '`' at the beginning and at the end of the statement: ! `if [ ! -s /sFTP/300072/in/ADJSTMNT.txt ]; then mv /sFTP/300072/in/ADJSTMNT.txt /sFTP/300072/inbkp; fi`